# cross domain event source

Tags: node.js, cross-domain, cors

I am trying to create an EventSource server using nodejs, that will server requests cross domain. I am sending back Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, but the browser (nor Chrome or Opera) won`t let me connect. There are the headers I send back:

```
this._response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
});
```

How can I do this the right way?

Regards

Comment: Opera does not support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

Comment: Maybe, but Chrome does support CORS, and I still get Security Exception (SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18). I believe there must be a hack, like Acces-Control-Allow-Origin for XHR, but I just couldn`t find it.

Comment: Although http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ has a section that shows how it can be used with SSE, it seems that browsers ignored it for now and there is no support for CORS+SSE at the moment.

Comment: Would love to have a confirmation of this ^, I'm having difficulty setting headers on the EventSource XHR.

Answer (score 4):

`Allow-Credentials` cannot be used with `Allow-Origin` set to `*`.
Consider writing the received Origin-header in your response.

Answer (score 3):

see https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource - polyfill can be adopted to support CORS for Firefox, Webkit and IE 8+

Answer (score 2):

Try the following block in place of yours. The browser will call one time with `OPTIONS` and then the request will be made as expected after that.

You won't need the `if` statement if you have broken out the request methods - but I wanted to give you a full block just in case you're hosting it like the *Hello World* example did.

```
if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    console.log('!OPTIONS');
    var headers = {};
    // IE8 does not allow domains to be specified, just the *
    // headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = req.headers.origin;
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = false;
    headers["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = '86400'; // 24 hours
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept";
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get `Security Exception (SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18)` if you are using cross domain resources. This could be due to :

1. trying to access local resources via `file://` (local files not served via node server) or
2. trying to access resources from another server that does not allow CORS or
3. maybe you are testing the page from the local file instead of from the URL served from your node server.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** When responding to a [credentialed requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#requests_with_credentials) request, the server **must** specify an origin in the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, instead of specifying the "`*`" wildcard.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests

So:

```js
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
```

(server-side)

**if client's `origin` (`req.headers.origin`) is trusted.**

---

Or simply set `{withCredentials: false}` (client-side) and use `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` if you don't need it.